# Insert a character at every nth instance in R

Tags: r

I have a vector called `myvec<- (c(141,143,139,139,140,141,138,140,142,138))`. 
How can I insert Y every n=3 instance of `,`?

The result I want is:
`141,143,139Y139,140,141Y138,140,142`

Comment: do you need a single string as output or a vector

Comment: I need a comma separated string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be we need

```
gsub("([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),", "\\1Y", paste(myvec, collapse=","))
```

---

To make this more generalizable, the pattern can be created with `strrep` and `sprintf`

```
createPattern <- function(n) {
   sprintf("(%s[^,]+),", strrep("[^,]+,", n-1))
 }

pat <- createPattern(3)
gsub(pat, "\\1Y", paste(myvec, collapse=","))
```

Comment: by the way, is there a way to automate [^,]+,[^,]+,[^,] for n?